# Playframework 2 messages file ignored when deploying to heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

I am trying to deploy a playframework-based app (play 2). When I run it locally, all is well. When I deploy to heroku, instead of reading the message from the message file, the app just spits out the message name. eg: this code:

```
@Message("app.title")
```

results in

```
app.title
```

rather than the value in the `conf/messages` file. Locally, it works fine.

Note that I'm not internationalizing my site, just using the default messages file in order to separate text from code (and maybe internationalize some day :)

Comment: Verify that the `conf/messages` was committed to the git repo.  Also verify that it runs locally in prod mode with `play start`.

Comment: `play start` works fine locally.

Comment: Indeed, I had originally named the file "Messages", and even though I renamed it, git did not. Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  Glad you figured it out.  Want to answer your own question?

Comment: Okay. It won't let me accept it yet. Not sure if I should add the "git" tag to this question. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that I had named my file "Messages", which was fine on Mac OS X (case-preserving but not case-sensitive file system), but not okay on Heroku. I realized this pretty quickly and fixed it, but unfortunately, git did not see the fix. I had to delete, commit, re-add and recommit. I suspect a name-change (not just case-change) would have been adequate as well.

Thanks to James Ward (who really answered this question) for the suggestion.

Comment: That's often mistake on Mac + git, solution is just as you wrote, rename the file (to something else), commit and re-rename it again to the proper case.